# How to get access token in Azure for Network Rest API?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Following are the Points by reference to the Azure Network API:

The following information is common to all tasks:

1. Replace {api-version} with 2015-06-15.
2. Replace {subscription-id} with your subscription identifier in the URI.
3. Replace {resource-group-name} with the resource group. For more information, see Using Resource groups to manage your Azure resources.
4. Set the Content-Type header to application/json.
5. Set the Authorization header to a JSON Web Token that you obtain from Azure Active Directory.

I am confused about the 5th point. Can you please guide me to how to get access token using Azure Active Directory?

Answer (score 5):

Azure Active Directory is built upon the oauth authentication protocols, as defined in RFC 6749 [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

The concept behind using tokens is that you can authenticate to a central authority and then have permissions granted to a separate system without needing to give that system your credentials.

*from [Service to Service Calls Using Client Credentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/azure/dn645543.aspx)*

[image: taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/azure/dn645543.aspx]

In this case if the server that was called in 3 was compromised, credentials would still be safe, and the attacker would only have access to resources until the token expired. Hence tokens are generally short lived.

You can obtain a token by making a POST request to `login.microsoftonline.com` with the following content

```
POST contoso.com/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=625bc9f6-3bf6-4b6d-94ba-e97cf07a22de&client_secret=qkDwDJlDfig2IpeuUZYKH1Wb8q1V0ju6sILxQQqhJ+s=&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F
```

Which will produce the following response

```
{
"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjdkRC1{shorted}",
"token_type":"Bearer",
"expires_in":"3599",
"expires_on":"1388452167",
"resource":"https://service.contoso.com/"
}
```

From this you can take the access token and use it in your application.

This is the authentication flow for Azure and it is not possible to change it to simply use a pre-configured token. Even if you use a certificate you still obtain a token with it and use that to authorise against resources.

Comment: I am working in GoLang. I'm using the REST API of Azure for Network management. I'm still confuse to how to get access token. I'm done with all the steps, have created AAD, granted it role/permissions. But stuck on how to get access token. Is there any way of getting the access token apart from the code?

Comment: @Baber I have modified the answer to address your question

Comment: Thank you. That really helped me a lot. I'll catch you again if I needed any further help :)

Comment: What is your host parameter? Is this a header parameter? What kind of URL is contoso.com/oauth2/token? I know that contoso is a fictional name used by microsoft. But how by which data of my API app and my Active Directory tenant do I have to replace in your POST request content?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an Azure AD service principal and then retrieve the authentication (JWT) token. The sample script below demonstrates creating an Azure AD service principle via PowerShell. For a more detailed walkthrough, please reference the guidance at [https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/#authenticate-service-principal-with-password—powershell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/#authenticate-service-principal-with-password---powershell). It is also possible to [create a service principal via the Azure portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/).

```
$pwd = “[your-service-principle-password]”
$subscriptionId = “[your-azure-subscription-id]”

Login-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

$azureAdApplication = New-AzureRmADApplication `
                        -DisplayName “ Demo Web name” `
                        -HomePage “https://localhost/webdemo” `
                        -IdentifierUris “https://localhost/webdemo” `
                        -Password $pwd

New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $azureAdApplication.ApplicationId
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Reader -ServicePrincipalName $azureAdApplication.ApplicationId

$subscription = Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
$creds = Get-Credential -UserName $azureAdApplication.ApplicationId -Message “Please use your service principle credentials”

Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $creds -ServicePrincipal -TenantI $subscription.TenantId
```

Not familiar with GoLang, but you can refer to the following .NET code to retrieve the access token for your application.

```
public static string GetAccessToken()
{
    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/{tenantId or tenant name}");  
    var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: "{client id}", clientSecret: "{application password}");
    var result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource: "https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential:credential);

    if (result == null) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
    }

    string token = result.AccessToken;

    return token;
}
```