# Is it possible to call external Azure Service with AD Token from within D365/PowerApp plugins?

Tags: azure, microsoft-dynamics

I am new to D365/PowerApps and wonder if i have a Azure Service, (Azure Functions or WebAPP) that is secured with Azure AD tokens (App Registrations).

Can I get an Access Token to my external services using Azure AD from within a plugin step in d365? How do I get such token on behalf of the context the plugin when running as a user.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Flow and compose a http request to get the token:

https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/edfa8fde25644f149448c8d8cff44699/call-a-web-service-from-a-powerapp/

Here's a good explanation on how to do it using the REST API:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36982924/1384539

Comment: So can you do that from a plugin step , like on create entity?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct,
You have an Azure function APP or external azure service and that is secured by creating Azure AD App with it's roles delegation and so on.

Now you need Access token for this Azure APP with client ID and Client Secret.

We had this similar thing in Dynamics 365 i.e When we wish to use Dynamics 365 Webapi, We need to create Azure AD App and then provide roles delegation so that this app will have access to Dynamics 365.

In Plugin we can give details with client Id and Secret and then generate Token which will be used for Furthure process during plugin Execution.

Note: Most of these plugins we run under System context.

Here are few examples which will lead you to your desired direction.

Most of the Examples also talk about creating Non-Interactive user in Dynamics but in your case that shall not be needed because you are not communicating with Dynamics via (Azure AD App) rather you communicate with Azure functions or so on.

1. [Link 1](https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/johntowgood/2018/03/08/dynamics-365-online-authenticate-with-client-credentials)
2. [Link 2](https://dev.to/benjsoft/how-to-obtain-an-oauth-access-token-in-dynamics-crm-365-online-using-c-283e)
3. [Link 3](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/generate-access-token-for-dynamics-365-single-tenant-server-to-server-authentica/)

Comment: I can make an application user that is backed by an azure Add App registration, ideally I would like to get the token on behalf of the application user without personally having to store the client secret in code or on a configuration entity. Is there any way to do the integration without me providing the client secret over in dynamic?

Comment: Look at how the Data Export service for d365 is made. It retrieves a keyvault secret without me giving it any secret to d365, just by giving the vault permission to be accessed by the app registration "Data Export Service for D365" - so somehow dynamics must have gotten that apps client secret automatically.